# Nesting Javascript if-else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to get the else-if nesting statement to work but nothing is coming through the browser

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var favColor = "Black";
var favNumber = 17;
var gender = "Male";
var birthPlace = "Perth";

    if(favColor=="Black"){
        if(favNumber==17;);{
            if(gender=="Male");{
                if(birthPlace=="Perth");{
                    document.write("Your infomation is correct");
                }else{
                    document.write("Invalid user infomation");
                }   
            }
        }


    }
</script>

</html>
```

What am i doing wrong ? 
Cheers

Comment: dont use semicolon(;) just after if()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given `;` in `if` condition which are causing nothing to show remove `;` from `if` conditions

```
if(favNumber==17;);{  //remove both semicolons ;
        if(gender=="Male");// remove ;
```

Comment: Thank you Leo ! 

I am still a novice on JS syntax so i might of overthink it.

Means a lot buddy :)

Comment: @Stephen.F please mark as answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was missing a } at the end and there was a terminator after 17 in the first if statement.

This code will work:

```
var favColor = "Black";
    var favNumber = 17;
    var gender = "Male";
    var birthPlace = "Perth";

    if(favColor=="Black") {
        if (favNumber == 17) {
            if (gender == "Male") {
                if (birthPlace == "Perth") {
                    document.write("Your infomation is correct");
                } else {
                    document.write("Invalid user infomation");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Use &&  in your code instead of nesting if statements.

```
var favColor = "Black";
var favNumber = 17;
var gender = "Male";
var birthPlace = "Perth";

if(favColor=="Black" 
        && favNumber == 17
        && gender == "Male" 
        && birthPlace == "Perth") {
    document.write("Your infomation is correct");
} else {
    document.write("Invalid user infomation");
}
```

Get in the habit of logging to the console. Its easier to debug as you can see exactly where the code is breaking. Furthermore, you can debug without changing your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You have many extra semicolons

```
var favColor = "Black";
var favNumber = 17;
var gender = "Male";
var birthPlace = "Perth";

    if(favColor=="Black"){
        if(favNumber==17){
            if(gender=="Male"){
                if(birthPlace=="Perth"){
                    document.write("Your infomation is correct");
                }else{
                    document.write("Invalid user infomation");
                }   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var favColor = "Black";
    var favNumber = 17;
    var gender = "Male";
    var birthPlace = "Perth";

        if(favColor=="Black"){
            if(favNumber==17){
                if(gender=="Male"){
                    if(birthPlace=="Perth"){
                        document.write("Your infomation is correct");
                    }else{
                        document.write("Invalid user infomation");
                    }   
                }
            }
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ezzXYp    Additional and unwanted semi colons caused error... works fine in codepen after removing them

Answer (score -1):

```
if(favColor=="Black"){
   if(favNumber==17){
      if(gender=="Male"){
         if(birthPlace=="Perth"){
            document.write("Your infomation is correct");
         }else{
       document.write("Invalid user infomation");
      }   
   }
}
```